# Docker connect to mysql container via remote software

Tags: mysql, docker, containers

I have created my docker environment, but is having trouble connecting to mysql via remote software e.g. Workbench or Sequel Pro. Below is my yml file for mysql specific.

```
  mysql-dev:
    image: mysql:8.0.17
    container_name: bcdb
    volumes:
      - mysql-dev:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpwd"
      MYSQL_USER: 'testuser'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'testpassword'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'testdb'
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    ports:
      - "3301:3306"
```

Note: The mysql-dev is connected to volumes mysql-dev:

No matter if I type in as hostname:
localhost, 127.0.0.1, (ip address of the mysql server) etc. there is no connection available. Error message is: "MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)"

Just a thought: Do I need to expose the ports in the Dockerfile, or am I missing something basic?

I'm starting the container by typing: "docker-compose up -d" - nothing else atm.

Answer (score 1):

Try bridge network,  here is a working yaml config,

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysql-dev:
    image: mysql:5
    container_name: bcdb
    # volumes:
    #   - mysql-dev:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpwd"
      MYSQL_USER: 'testuser'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'testpassword'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'testdb'
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    ports:
      - "3301:3306"
    networks:
      - mysql-main

networks:
  mysql-main:
    driver: bridge
```

Test connection:

```
➜  ~ nc 127.0.0.1 3301
J
5.7.34OEaDdC���;2
Bpq?7O{mysql_native_password


^C
➜  ~
```

For the details, you can refer this [excellent blog post](https://severalnines.com/blog/single-host-networking-mysql-containers-docker/).

Comment: Still the same result :/. Host: 127.0.0.1